# Projective general linear groups of order 2 = projective special linear group of order 2

Tags: group-theory

If $q\geq 5$ is a prime and we consider the group PGL(2,q) the projective general linear group of order 2 and the group PSL(2,q) the projective special linear group of order 2.

Can I then conclude PSL(2,q) = PGL(2,q)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cokernel of the embedding $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q) \to \mathrm{PGL}(2,q)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_q^*/(\mathbb F_q^*)^2$, that is you will have equality exactly iff every element of $\mathbb F_q$ is a square. For $q = 5$ for example, we have $\mathbb F_5^* = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $(\mathbb F_5^*)^2 = \{1,4\}$, so $\mathrm{PSL}(2,5) < \mathrm{PGL}(2,5)$.